# is there a function without an input but return something

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_MULTAS_TOTAL 
RETURN INTEGER
IS 
V_TOTAL INT;
BEGIN 
SELECT SUM(MULTA)
INTO V_TOTAL
FROM DETALLE_ARRIENDO;
RETURN V_TOTAL;
END;
```

im working on SQL Developer 11 and i have to call it with

```
exec FN_MULTAS_TOTAL;
```

and get an integer value

Answer (score 5):

No problem with such a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function fn_multas_total
  2    return integer
  3  is
  4    v_total int;
  5  begin
  6    select sum(multa)
  7    into v_total
  8    from detalle_arriendo;
  9  return v_total;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

However, you don't call it with `exec` - it is used in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or some other tools which support it; it is a "shortcut" for an anonymous `begin-end` PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> exec p_test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2    p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It is used for **procedures**, not functions. You can't just

```
SQL> begin
  2    detalle_arriendo;
  3  end;
  4  /
  detalle_arriendo;
  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00221: 'DETALLE_ARRIENDO' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

which means that you have to declare a variable and fetch function's result into it, e.g.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result number;
  3  begin
  4    l_result := fn_multas_total;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Usually, we use functions as

```
SQL> select fn_multas_total from dual;

FN_MULTAS_TOTAL
---------------
            100

SQL>
```

If you desperately want to use `exec`, then you still have to declare a variable and

```
SQL> var result number
SQL> exec :result := fn_multas_total;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :result

    RESULT
----------
       100

SQL>
```